# EF 3.1 Core (Newbie) Access One to Many in View

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-4.0, ef-core-3.1

I've just started developing in C# using ASP.Net Core and EntityFramework.  I am having some difficulty trying to figure out how to access and save my address data specifically. In a nutshell, I have companies that have at least two addresses which are a billing address and a service address.

I have three Models (note, I've paired down the properties for the purposes of this post).

**Company Model:**

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses {get; set;}
```

**Address Model:**

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public int CompanyId {get; set;}
public string street1 {get; set;} 
public AddressTypeId {get; set;
public AddressType AddressType {get; set;}
public virtual Company Company {get; set;}
```

**Address Type Model:**

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public string AddressType {get; set;}
```

I'm using EF with eager loading.  I'm able to load my Company based on an ID and I am also able to show an **EDIT View** that has all of my company details but I don't know how to load the different addresses (billing and service) into the view so that they can be edited and committed back to the database. I only want to edit the Service and Billing Addresses.

My Controller has the following code:

```
CompanyDetailsViewModel companyDetailsViewModel = new CompanyDetailsViewModel();
var company = _companyRepository.GetCompanyById(id);
var addresses = company.Addresses;
Address serviceAddress = null;
Address billingAddress = null;

foreach (var address in addresses)
   {
     switch (address.AddressType.Display.ToLower())
     {
       case "service":
          serviceAddress = address;
          break;
       case "billing":
          billingAddress = address;
          break;
       }
      }

  companyDetailsViewModel.Company = company;
  companyDetailsViewModel.BillingAddress = billingAddress;
  companyDetailsViewModel.ServiceAddress = serviceAddress;
  return View(companyDetailsViewModel);
```

**Here's what I have in the ViewModel**

```
 public Company Company { get; set; }       
    public List<CompanyType> CompanyTypeList { get; set; }
    public List<CompanySource> CompanySourceList { get; set; }
    public List<State> StateList { get; set; }
    public string EncodedAddress { get; set; }
    public Address ServiceAddress { get; set; }
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
```

**And a portion of the View**

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Company.Name" class="form-control" />
<input asp-for="@Model.ServiceAddress.Street1" class="form-control"/>
<input asp-for="@Model.ServiceAddress.Street2" class="form-control" />
<input asp-for="@Model.ServiceAddress.City" class="form-control" />
<select asp-for="@Model.ServiceAddress.StateId" class="form-control"
    asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.StateList,"Id","StateAbbreviation"))">
</select>
<input asp-for="@Model.ServiceAddress.PostalCode" class="form-control" />
```

Hopefully this is making sense.  It's a little difficult to explain.

Note that I know why the data isn't being updated (it's because I'm using separate classes in the ViewModel for the Service and Billing addresses) but I just don't know how to wire those up which led to this question. :-)

Thanks a bunch for the assistance.

--- Val

Comment: It is possible to loop in the view using razor syntax. Are you having some difficulty with it?  Care to give it a try and show the view snippet?

Comment: Since you're taking only certain addresses from a list of addresses, the only thing you can do is manually update those addresses individually, which then means you need to include the address id in the form so that you can look up the correct address to update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris.  I realized that I was passing the VIEWMODEL from the controller to the view and returning only the COMPANY model to the controller when updating so not every property was being set. I'm making progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Edit View, you need to use the `hidden control` to store the current `Company Id` field, otherwise you will not know which item of data is currently modified.

You should display all the type of addresses on the page, then modify the corresponding data and pass it to the controller, and then `edit the corresponding address according to the id value`.

For details, refer to the following code.(I simplified the code based on the fields you provided and i'm using ef core)

Edit View:

```
@model WebApplication_core_mvc.Controllers.CompanyDetailsViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
   <input asp-for="@Model.Company.Id" class="form-control" hidden />
   CompanyName: <input asp-for="@Model.Company.Name" class="form-control" />
   BillingAddress:  <input asp-for="@Model.BillingAddress.street1" class="form-control" />
   ServiceAddress: <input asp-for="@Model.ServiceAddress.street1" class="form-control" />
    <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="button" />
</form>
@*<input asp-for="@Model.ServiceAddress.Street2" class="form-control" />
    <input asp-for="@Model.ServiceAddress.City" class="form-control" />
    <select asp-for="@Model.ServiceAddress.StateId" class="form-control"
            asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.StateList,"Id","StateAbbreviation"))">
    </select>
    <input asp-for="@Model.ServiceAddress.PostalCode" class="form-control" />*@
```

Controller:

```
public class CompanyAddressController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;
    public CompanyAddressController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        CompanyDetailsViewModel companyDetailsViewModel = new CompanyDetailsViewModel();
        var company = _context.CompanyModel.Include(x => x.Addresses).ThenInclude(x => x.AddressType).Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        var addresses = company.Addresses;
        AddressModel serviceAddress = null;
        AddressModel billingAddress = null;

        foreach (var address in addresses)
        {
            switch (address.AddressType.AddressType.ToLower())
            {
                case "service":
                    serviceAddress = address;
                    break;
                case "billing":
                    billingAddress = address;
                    break;
            }
        }

        companyDetailsViewModel.Company = company;
        companyDetailsViewModel.BillingAddress = billingAddress;
        companyDetailsViewModel.ServiceAddress = serviceAddress;
        return View(companyDetailsViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(CompanyDetailsViewModel companyDetailsViewModel)
    {
        var xx = _context.CompanyModel.Include(x => x.Addresses).ThenInclude(x => x.AddressType).Where(x => x.Id == companyDetailsViewModel.Company.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        foreach (var address in xx.Addresses)
        {
            switch (address.AddressType.AddressType.ToLower())
            {
                case "service":
                    address.street1 = companyDetailsViewModel.ServiceAddress.street1;
                    break;
                case "billing":
                    address.street1 = companyDetailsViewModel.BillingAddress.street1;
                    break;
            }
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  It's all beginning to make sense to me.  You example helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change the AddressType to Enum and store it in address model

```html
public int Id {get; set;}
public int CompanyId {get; set;}
public string street1 {get; set;} 
public AddressType AddressType {get; set;}
public virtual Company Company {get; set;}
```

```html
public enum AddressType
    {
        Billing = 1,
        Service = 2
    }
```

create for each loop for address and edit them

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Since I can't always assume that ID=1 will be billing and ID=2 will be Service I can't really use an Enum.  The ID is an identity column in my table.